# Model-Viewer AR mode: in Android the GLB model is wrong scale on initial load

Tags: android, augmented-reality, gltf, webxr, model-viewer

On Android devices, when I load a GLB file in AR mode on model-viewer, it appears at the wrong scale and is not on the ground level when I first see it rendered. Users have to lower their device to floor level before the model scales up the to proper size. The USDZ gets used on iOS devices and renders fine with QuickLook.

These are large models, sometimes as large as 18 by 18 feet.

Here are my settings:

```
<model-viewer 
    id="model-viewer"
    src="mymodel.glb" 
    ios-src="mymodel.usdz" 
    ar 
    ar-scale="fixed" 
    scale="0.01 0.01 0.01" 
    exposure="0.8"
    ar-placement="floor" 
    ar-modes = "webxr scene-viewer quick-look"
    camera-controls 
    touch-action="pan-y" 
    alt="Kitchen Model" 
    environment-image="legacy"
  >
```

For the record, I have tried having the model at a smaller scale and then setting the model-viewer to scale 1. It does not affect this problem.

What can I do to make this render properly on first load?